# SQL server 2008 and 2012 on the same instance of Windows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it a problem to have both of these installed on the same Windows instance? I.e. will one break the other or impact it negatively in any way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it a problem to have both of these installed on the same Windows instance?

Typically, no.

> will one ... impact (the other) ... in any way?

Some SQL Server components cannot exist side-by-side, like the SQL Server Browser Service. This *must* be the newer version, but should be backwards compatible with old versions of SQL Server.

In practice, I've never seen this be any more than a consideration, it's never manifested into a problem.

Answer (score 3):

There's a [comprehensive answer on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143694.aspx).

Things to note:

- If a default instance already exists on the computer, SQL Server must be installed as a named instance
- Anything earlier than 2005 is not supported
- If you are using a failover cluster setup, you have to avoid IP conflicts by using a non standard port

Other than that yes, I’ve seen 2005 and 2008 work happily on the same server, and it seems the same is true for 2012